# Save csv file in each iteration of loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how can i save each CSV file in iteration on a pandas data frame.

Like i need to save each file as newcsv_1, newcsv_2, newcsv_3 .....

I have used it for loop but it is starting saving from 0 ex:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    df = pd.Dataframe(arr[i])

    df.to_csv("newcsv_{}".format(i))
```

newcsv_0,
newcsv_1,
newcsv_2

but I do not want to save it from 0 want to save it from 1

Comment: Add 1 to `i` on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_csv("newcsv_{}.csv".format(i+1))
```

Comment: To be helpful, your answer ought to include some explanation to help the user understand why the code in your answer will solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
    df = pd.Dataframe(arr[i])

    df.to_csv("newcsv_{}".format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df.to_csv("newcsv_{}.csv".format(i+1))
```

A better way is to:

```
df.to_csv(f"newcsv_{i+1}.csv") # f-string format python 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add +1 `df.to_csv(f"newcsv_{i+1}")`

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    df = pd.Dataframe(arr[i])

    df.to_csv(f"newcsv_{i+1}")
```

or you can start loop to 1 and then at the end +1.

```
for i in range(1, len(arr)+1):
    df = pd.Dataframe(arr[i])

    df.to_csv(f"newcsv_{i}")
```